# What decides the color of the tab bar in a Xamarin.Forms tabbed page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to use the same color for the background of an area at the top of one of my screens.

Does anyone know how is this color decided. Is that something Xamarin preset or is it an iOS and Android present color?

Comment: On Android it is defined by theme, on iOS it is system defined but you can change both of them

Comment: I would like to find out where it's defined for iOS.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is Adam's answer is not enough?

Comment: @SamanthaJ - it is set by the TabbedPageRenderer.cs in iOS (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/TabbedRenderer.cs). In this file, look at the UpdateBarBackgroundColor and UpdateBarTextColor to see the exact properties it changes on the TabBarItem iOS Native Control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are defaults in each platform. Android via it's theme and iOS by default properties.

However if you want to change it, you can do this in your Xamarin.Forms project.

```
var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage()
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
                BarTextColor = Color.White
            };
```

Or set those properties in XAML.

Comment: How do we add a custom color? In hex values? In XAML, I mean.